# Поиск и анализ кластеров в матрице.

Tags: матрицы, кластеризация

[image]

Добрый день. Нужно понять какой алгоритм применять. 
Голово пока не работает, может быть здесь очень просто.

Матрица двумерная. Каждая клетка принадлежит определенному кластеру.
В ней острова и моря.(кластеры)
Есть 3 острова.
И 2 моря.

Известно:

- Известны кластеры соседи. То есть 'остров 1' и 'море 1' соседи. Но 'море 1' и 'море 2' не соседи, так как не имеют смежных клеток.
- Известно, какая клетка матрицы принадлежит какому кластеру.
- Известно, связаны ли кластеры между собой.(в данном примере не связаны)
- Можно проверять путь из одной клетки в другую.

Нужно определить уровень вложенности кластеров по отношению друг к другу.
Вот это сложно объяснить.

Например

- 'остров 1' и 'море 1' соседи и их уровен вложенности **0**
- 'остров 1' и 'остров 2' не соседи и их уровен вложенности **1**, так как их самые ближайшие друг к другу клетки разделяет 1 кластер другого типа.
- 'остров 1' и 'остров 3'  не соседи и их уровень вложенности **2**, так как их самые ближайшие друг к другу клетки разделяет 2 кластера другого типа('море 2' , 'море 1') и 1 кластер такого же типа('остров 2').

Сделать это в уме просто, а вот какой это алгоритм и из какой области не понятно. То ли кластеризация, то ли графы.

Comment: "уровень вложенности" это относительная величина ? определяется наименьшим количеством пересеченных кластеров(или (границ кластеров/2) ) ? например море1-море2=1 море2-остров1=2 остров2-остров3=1 ?

Comment: ага спасибо.)
Простейший алгоритм на графах оказывается.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну в общем если соседи известны - то это граф (объедините соседние кластеры одного типа в ноду, т.е. их соседи - наши соседи), соответственно алгоритм кратчайшего пути в графе и будет вашим решением.